# Background image covered up when scroll to the bottom

Tags: html, css

The background image is covered by white area when you scroll all the way to the bottom. Cannot seem to figure out what it is. Played with each of the selectors and HTML. Would appreciate help. Please click link go to the CodePen where the code is visible.

https://codepen.io/siamazing/pen/QaGdWq

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  }

#body { 
            background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/267278/pexels-photo-267278.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb) ;
            background-position: center center;
            background-repeat:  no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size:  cover;
            background-color: #999;
      height: 100%;
      font-size: 15px;}

.container-fluid {
  padding-top: 20px; 
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  height: 100%;}

h2 {
  padding-left: 20px; 
  font-family: 'pacifico';
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #72777f;
  }

header {
  text-align: center; 
  font-family: 'pacifico'; 
  }

article {
  font-family: 'raleway'; 
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.4);   
  color: #303338;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 30px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `height:100%`  from `#body`

https://codepen.io/mirohristov/pen/MrbmWj

Answer (score 1):

See Miro's answer, but here's some troubleshooting advice.

I added * { outline: 1px dashed red; } and saw this:

[image]

That made it easier to find the culprit element - #body and remove the height:100%; rule.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I see the arrow - which element is the white apart of? I removed it and it worked, but trying to understand what caused it.

Comment: By setting the height to 100% instead of leaving it at the default value of height: auto, you are telling it to limit itself to 100% of the parent element. In the codepen from the question, the parent was .container-fluid with height:100%, and then the body element with height 100%. All of that is rendered inside of an iframe which has a finite height that affects all of those children. Leave the 100% off of height unless you are intentionally limiting an elements height by limiting its parent element's height and you'll be golden!